# Getting selected Index from DropDownListFor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I am trying to get the index of selected item from a dropdownlist in my mvc view. I populated the content of the ddl using enums and the code looks something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateId,  Enum.GetNames(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.States)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }),"--Market--",new { style = "width: 80px;font-size:85%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px"})
```

Just so you guys know the enum is defined in my model class:

```
public enum States { ANY, FL, TX, GA, NE };
```

My controller looks something like below:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("hello");
        var model = new DropDownModel();


        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DropDownModel model)
    {
        // Get the selected value
        int stateId = model.SelectedStateId;
        int paymentTypeId = model.SelectedBillTypeId;

        BillingToolInterface_1.check.a = stateId;
        BillingToolInterface_1.check.b = paymentTypeId;

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello");

        Debug.WriteLine(stateId.ToString());

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

I am printing the value of selectedstateid on debug console after the submit button in my view is pressed. But it is displaying "0" for every selected value. It should display 1,2,3 and so on while corresponding value is selected in my state drop down.

PS: ddl -> dropdownlist

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're not setting the value in your dropdownlist?

Comment: Isn't that automatically taken care of while dropdownlist is populated (in my case from enums). If not how should I set the value in this case.

Comment: I'm looking into it. Just a sec.

Comment: Are you're suring the code you posted is working, don't receive exceptions on your controller?

Comment: My mistake, I made a typo, sorry

Comment: Ok, I found the solution and I'm writing it for the moment. Please hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you create your select list, you're only assigning a text value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateId,  Enum.GetNames(typeof(BTSWeb.Models.States)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }),"--Market--",new { style = "width: 80px;font-size:85%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px"})
```

When you run that kind of code in your browser, you'll see:

[image]

When you modify your code like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.States, Enum.GetNames(typeof(WebApplication1.Controllers.States)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e, Value = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(WebApplication1.Controllers.States), e)).ToString() }), "--Market--", new { style = "width: 80px;font-size:85%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px" })
```

Now, you're also passing the value of the enum:

[image]

You'll notice on how that rendered HTML of your select list changes? You have a value property right now.

I've written a demo project which explains it (I tried to stay as close as possible to your code).

First the enumeration:

```
public enum States { ANY, FL, TX, GA, NE };
```

Then the model:

```
public class DropDownModel
{
    public States States = new States();
    public int SelectedStateID { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new DropDownModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DropDownModel model)
    {
        // Get the selected value

        return View();
    }
}
```

Now there's the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Default", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStateID, Enum.GetNames(typeof(WebApplication1.Controllers.States)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e, Value = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(WebApplication1.Controllers.States), e)).ToString() }), "--Market--", new { style = "width: 80px;font-size:85%;border-radius: 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px" })

    <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" />
}
```

And basiccly, that's all their is.
Now, run your application, and in the dropdownlist select the 3rd element (This should be 'TX').

When you look at the properties of your model passed into your controller again, you'll notfice the following:

[image]

You see that States has the INCORRECT value, but that the selected index property has 2. This is correct, because of the following:

In the declaration of your dropdownlist, you bind it to SelectedStateId.

Also the value of 2 is correct because an enumeration with no values starts at 0 for the first element and adds 1 for every following element.

When you want the state now, you can convert your integer value (2) to the enumeration value.

So, a long post but I hope it helped.

Comment: Worked like a charm, The new problem I am having now is that --Market- isn't being displayed as the default ddl text. Instead it's displaying "any" as the default text. Any ideas why that might be happening.

Comment: You'll notice that the .Select function is an extension method, so you should write your own extension method that returns an IEnumerable of SelectListItem objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot continue my research right now, but bascilly, you should write an extension method that return you a collection of SelectListItem. It shouldn't be that hard. Also, if my answer has helped you in any way, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Hi, yes it did work but for some reason I am not able to accept your answer. Will try in a while.

Comment: That's weird. But I'm glad that you find a way to write the extension method for the default value. Maybe add it as an update in your original question...

Comment: @nitinsh99 - most likely the Any is defaulting because you SelectedStateId is an int, which does not allow null values.  Notice that any has a value of 0, which is default value of an int.  You need to use a nullable int if you want to use the default selection text --Market--